# Spark - Cosmos - connector problems

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-cosmosdb, azure-hdinsight

I am playing around with the Azure Spark-CosmosDB connector which lets you access CosmosDB nodes directly from a Spark cluster for analytics using Jupyter on HDINsight

I have been following the steps described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector),including uploading the required jars to Azure storage and executing the %%configure magic to prepare the environment.

But it always seems to terminate due to an I/O exception when trying to open the jar (see yarn log below)

```
17/10/09 20:10:35 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Error accessing /mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1507534135641_0014/container_1507534135641_0014_01_000001/azure-cosmosdb-spark-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar)
17/10/09 20:10:35 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/10/09 20:10:35 INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Error accessing /mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1507534135641_0014/container_1507534135641_0014_01_000001/azure-cosmosdb-spark-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar)`
```

Not sure whether this is related to the jar not being copied to the worker nodes.

any idea? thanks, Nick

Comment: u need to add those jars into ExecutablePath property, based on the IDE you have to add those jars. I think you are using Spark with java

Comment: By any chance did you download the JARs from GitHub via the browser instead of git/GitHub desktop?  If so, it may be that you need to download the JARs as RAW.  And to confirm, are the JARs sitting in the default storage of the HDI cluster?

Comment: You might have a point here with me downloading via the browser. Let me try that

Comment: I found that the jars had conflicts with Jackson versions in other jars when I copied directly into head and worker node dirs on path.  However, I was able to supply to the spark job itself as a configuration on submit and get past the yarn/spark startup phase.  I saw failure occurring consistently in the Spark Thrift Servers, so I would check those logs for more detailed errors.